# Comparison with previous iteration in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, while-loop

I have the following `while` loop where I try to calculate an equation and I would like to add an `if` condition for the equation output to compare the results with the previous iteration. You see my attempt so far but it doesn't work!

```
Tin1 = 1.0
stepsize = 0.0001
const = 0.09929
cor = 25000

value_out = []

while Tin1 < 2:
    EQ = (Tin1**(3.125))*np.absolute(1-Tin1**(-1.5))
    Tin1 = Tin1+stepsize
    if (EQ[i] > const) and (EQ[i-1] < const):
       value = Tin1
       value_cor = value * cor
       value_out.append(value_cor)
```

Comment: You tried to use `i` but there is no `i`. Have you tried setting `i` to 0 before the loop and incrementing it by 1 in every iteration?

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: My question is about how can I implement an if statement for a while loop. Do I first need to collect all my output in a separate list and do a second loop for if condition, or is it possible to check the data in the same loop. I am a bit new to python so I do not know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could kep track of the previous value in a variable, and compare the current value to that one.

Maybe like this:

```
Tin1 = 1.0
stepsize = 0.0001
const = 0.09929
cor = 25000

value_out = []

previous = None
while Tin1 < 2:
    EQ = (Tin1**(3.125)) * np.absolute(1 - Tin1**(-1.5))
    Tin1 = Tin1 + stepsize
    if previous is not None and (EQ > const) and (previous < const):
        value = Tin1
        value_cor = value * cor
        value_out.append(value_cor)
    previous = EQ
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a variable storing the value of the previous iteration choosing its initial value to ensure that the comparison is false on the first iteration (since there is no previous value at this time) :

```
import sys

Tin1 = 1.0
stepsize = 0.0001
const = 0.09929
cor = 25000
previous = sys.float_info.max
value_out = []

while Tin1 < 2:
    EQ = (Tin1**(3.125))*np.absolute(1-Tin1**(-1.5))
    Tin1 = Tin1+stepsize
    if (EQ[i] > const) and (previous < const):
       value = Tin1
       value_cor = value * cor
       value_out.append(value_cor)
    previous = EQ[i]
```